# How do I inspect local variables or use the watch window with Rust code using VSCode and LLDB?

Tags: rust, visual-studio-code, lldb

I am trying to debug a Rust application using VSCode, but I am unable to inspect any local variables or use the watch window (see attached).

All breakpoints work fine, I just cannot view any variables, etc.

- VSCode v1.19.1
- Linux Elementary (latest)
- LLDB Debugger 0.7.3

The LLDB is what is shown in VSCODE plugin, but when I do `lldb --version` from the terminal it says: `lldb version 3.8.0 ( revision )`.

I get no errors when starting lldb from the terminal.  All breakpoints are hit while debugging, I just cannot see any of the variable values.

For the sake of completeness, I verified python scripting support as a Prerequisite listed on:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vadimcn.vscode-lldb

**

python-lldb-3.8 is already the newest version

**

[image: No local or watch]

Comment: I may have found the solution buried within the vscode manual that lists a bug for the current version of lldb i am using::
https://github.com/vadimcn/vscode-lldb/blob/master/MANUAL.md

Note: There is a known incompatibility of debug info emitted by rustc and LLDB 3.8: you won't be able to step through code or inspect variables if you have this version

I will try to upgrade or downgrade and report back

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct solution was to install LLDB 3.9. I can now inspect local variables, use the watch window, and see values via tooltips.

Here are the steps:

1. Install LLVM 3.9. I found [the accepted answer in this SE post](https://askubuntu.com/a/799998/538597) to be the easiest way.
2. Update Python LLDB to this version as per [the vscode-lldb wiki](https://github.com/vadimcn/vscode-lldb/wiki/Installing-LLDB). For example, I ran `sudo apt-get install python-lldb-3.9`

   3. Since LLVM now is invoked as `llvm-3.9` (instead of just `llvm`) then VSCode may not recognize it and complain that LLVM is not installed or supported.  My solution (yours may vary) was to remove then reinstall the VSCode extensions  "LLDB Debugger 0.7.3" and "Native Debug 0.21.2"

Once this was done and VSCode was restarted, I started to debug with <kbd>F5</kbd> then VSCode gave me an alert that a different LLDB was found (3.9) and asked to update to new executable - say yes and you should be good to go.

Results:

[image: debugging session]

Comment: I am using code 1.41.1 on Ubuntu 18.04, VSCode does not prompt me for different LLDB version. It will be very helpful if you can share your `launch.json` file.

Comment: So, I'm using rust-analyzer and lldb and debugging works fine if I use the code lens rust-analyzer adds. However, if one of my variables has a very long value (let's say a Json payload) and I try to copy the value from the debug windows it will stop at one point and return an ellipsis so the value is not complete. Is there a way to get the complete value for long variables? I hope I'm just missing something

Answer (score 1):

lldb doesn't "real" have support for Rust.  It uses the C++ type system to support Rust types, and uses the C++ expression parser for expressions.  So while simple things should work, more complex language features aren't well supported by "rust as C++".

It's possible to add language support for languages not directly supported by the clang front-end to lldb (see for instance the Go & OCaml support).

Tom Tromey is working on an actual Rust port for lldb, see: https://archive.fosdem.org/2018/schedule/event/rustdebug/ where he discusses this project, for instance.  He hasn't submitted the results to mainline lldb yet, but his fork is available at https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/lldb/commits/rust if anybody interested in Rust debugging in lldb wants to lend a hand.

Comment: *lldb doesn't have support for Rust* — citation and/or clarification required. Counterpoints [1](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/announcing-lldb-for-vscode/6183), [2](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/use-rust-gdb-and-rust-lldb-for-improved-debugging-you-already-have-them/756), [3](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/etc/rust-lldb).

Comment: And here's [an LLDB session where I print out some simple variables](https://gist.github.com/shepmaster/1b5dc43e38a89dd4d56d34e730238b01).

Comment: @Jim - from all of my research it appears to be mentioned many times over with people successfully using LLDB with Rust on Linux, for example:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vadimcn.vscode-lldb  (which mentions Rust support in last bullet)

  https://klausi.github.io/rustnish/2017/05/28/using-visual-studio-code-for-rust-on-ubuntu.html

Comment: How right you are.  In late 2016 somebody instructed lldb to "pretend Rust is C++" as a workaround to not actually supporting Rust.  So while I still contend it is correct to say lldb doesn't actually support Rust (since it is using a C++ compiler system to comprehend its types & parse expressions) to the extent that Rust looks like C++, printing variables should work after that patch.  You're probably going to have a lot less luck with the expression parser, however.